# Is it possible to place accordion inside title section on a card or in that space?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, slds

I am trying to get an `accordion` in the space the `title` of a `lightning-card` is placed, so I am utilizing all of the space that I can. But instead all I can do is place it outside of the `lightning-card` or below by quite a bit. Any solutions on this? I am not even sure this is possible, but want to check with others.

**Accordion above card**:
[image: accordion above lightning-card]

```
<template>
    <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open
                         onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
                         active-section-name={activeSections}>
        <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
            <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
            <p>Donec vitae tellus egestas, faucibus ipsum ac, imperdiet erat. Nam venenatis non ante at sagittis. Integer vel purus eget nunc semper placerat. Nam tristique quam leo, et posuere enim condimentum quis. Ut sagittis libero id lectus tempor maximus. Nunc ut tincidunt eros, a hendrerit leo. Suspendisse quis fermentum dolor. Nulla euismod consectetur leo, id condimentum nunc consequat quis.</p>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
        <lightning-card  title="">
            <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
            
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Accordion far down card**:
[image: accordion below many pixels below title area of lightning-card]

```
<template>
        <lightning-card>
            <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open
                         onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
                         active-section-name={activeSections}>
        <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
            <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
            <p>Donec vitae tellus egestas, faucibus ipsum ac, imperdiet erat. Nam venenatis non ante at sagittis. Integer vel purus eget nunc semper placerat. Nam tristique quam leo, et posuere enim condimentum quis. Ut sagittis libero id lectus tempor maximus. Nunc ut tincidunt eros, a hendrerit leo. Suspendisse quis fermentum dolor. Nulla euismod consectetur leo, id condimentum nunc consequat quis.</p>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Ideally**:
[image: title on lightning-card stating accordion should be there]

```
<template>
        <lightning-card  title="Accordion in this location">
            <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open
                         onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
                         active-section-name={activeSections}>
        <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
            <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
            <p>Donec vitae tellus egestas, faucibus ipsum ac, imperdiet erat. Nam venenatis non ante at sagittis. Integer vel purus eget nunc semper placerat. Nam tristique quam leo, et posuere enim condimentum quis. Ut sagittis libero id lectus tempor maximus. Nunc ut tincidunt eros, a hendrerit leo. Suspendisse quis fermentum dolor. Nulla euismod consectetur leo, id condimentum nunc consequat quis.</p>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Without button still shows it with quite a bit of space missing:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lightning-card supports title slot, so if you want to place your HTML into the title you can do it the following way (example from documentation)

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h3 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            Card Title
        </h3>
        <div slot="footer">
                <lightning-badge label="Tag1"></lightning-badge>
                <lightning-badge label="Tag2"></lightning-badge>
                <lightning-badge label="Tag3"></lightning-badge>
        </div>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

applying this to your example, it'll look like this:

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
    <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-accordion slot="title" 
                         allow-multiple-sections-open
                         onsectiontoggle={handleSectionToggle}
                         active-section-name={activeSections}>
      <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Accordion Title A">
        <p>This is the content area for section A.</p>
        <p>Donec vitae tellus egestas, faucibus ipsum ac, imperdiet erat. Nam venenatis non ante at sagittis. Integer
          vel purus eget nunc semper placerat. Nam tristique quam leo, et posuere enim condimentum quis. Ut sagittis
          libero id lectus tempor maximus. Nunc ut tincidunt eros, a hendrerit leo. Suspendisse quis fermentum dolor.
          Nulla euismod consectetur leo, id condimentum nunc consequat quis.</p>
      </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

I tested it in the playground and it seems to be working
[image]